# RootViewController's constraints get removed after calling VNDocumentCameraViewController

Tags: ios, swift

After presenting and dismissing the VNDocumentCameraViewController, I get a black screen. After some research, I found that a few constraints disappear after dismissing the camera view controller.

Here is a comparison of the view hierarchy before and after the VNDocumentCameraViewController.

[image]

Changes I noticed:

1. `UILayoutContainerView`'s constraints are completely gone
2. `RootTabBarContoller`'s constraints are halved.
3. "Position and size are ambiguous" sign

And here is the view hierarchy when the VNDocumentCameraViewController is present.

[image]

The root view controller is initialized in a scene delegate like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
        return
    }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.rootViewController = RootTabBarController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

I was thinking to try a storyboard as the initial scene but all my views use XIBs and I could not find how to import them into a storyboard.

Does the root view controller (`RootTabBarController` in my case) need extra constraints or some other configuration in order to sustain such transitions?

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was rather trivial. For some reason, the `RootTabBarController` had `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` line that caused the issue with the constraints.

Removing this line solved the issue.